# Can I set up abc.com and abc.com/abc two independant sites

Tags: url, dns, domain-name

I'm trying to set up two separate website eg. www.abc.com and www.abc.com/zyz. Is there any way to achieve this without using URL rewriting or using sub domain.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why not setup www.abc.com and zyz.abc.com? that will make it separate website more clear.

Comment: It is a business requirement. These two are using two separate technologies so can't be hosted under a single IIS website node but end users want to access the information using the second website using a pattern www.abc.com/zyz